# SSDT How to ignore dependency projects

Tags: sql, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

We have 3 databases: UntouchDB, Work1DB and Work2DB. 

UntouchDB is very large with over 100 tables, views for each their type. 

We're planning to use SSDT with Git to manage version of DB. In fact, it's easy to use in that way. We created 2 SSDT projects and import as database of Work1DB and Work2DB. Both of them reference to UntouchDB. 

The problem is UntouchDB is forbidden to touch. It means we cannot create its SSDT project. As the results, 2 projects are built fail. 

I tried to get DACPAC of UntouchDB and it costs 8.5MB, when we created reference as DACPAC for Work1DB and Work2DB project, they cost too much time to analysis and build. It seems never successfully build, it drops every time.

How to ignore dependency project UntouchDB from the remaining DB? 
I really need your help because I searched a lot on Google but always need create reference as DACPAC or as Database. Just on case nearly work is set error file properties "Extended T-SQL Verification" to FALSE. But then it jumps out with Computed Column cannot resolved error.

My question is:

- How to ignore dependency project UntouchDB from the remaining DB?
- How to fix Computed Column cannot resolved error as I mentioned above?

Comment: How many objects do you actually use from "UntouchDB"? You may want to create a scaled down version of that database with just those necessary objects and reference just that.  You could also create a new project, then use a Schema Compare to pull in just the objects you need to reference. Build _that_ project to get your "UntouchDB" reference dacpac to use in the other projects.

Comment: Thank @PeterSchott, I did as you said, how about server variable when I use linked server on Work1DB and Work2DB and need update all sps or views follow the format. When I use Schema Compare with target, it said I gonna delete view

Comment: Schema Compare will let you uncheck objects so you don't have to delete them. As for variables for objects such as linked servers, you create those at the Project level and then reference them in code as $(VariableName). (e.g., $(LinkedServer1).MyDB.dbo.Object)  Set the variable on your command line or in your Publish Profile, the latter being a little easier to maintain.

Comment: Thank @PeterSchott for helping me :)